# Write multi colored text to an image in .net

Tags: .net, image-processing, gdi+

I need to write some text to an image file in .net and have some of the words within the string be highlighted with a different color. How can I do this?

Within GDI+ for instance, I don't think writing out a series of separate text fields is going to work because all the text needs to be aligned and positioned as a single string.

Cheers, Ian.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, writing them out as separate text fields is your only option. You could use `graphics.MeasureString()` to find out how to exactly align them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the image in a `Graphics` and then call `DrawString` with the color you want.
This is a pseudo-not so pseudo code to use:

```
var img = Bitmap.FromFile("filename.png");
            var g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
            g.DrawString("xxx", new Font("Arial", 10), Brushes.Yellow, new PointF(10, 10));
            img.Save("filename.png");
```

Play with it, I did not try this specific sample but I usually go this way.

Comment: Aha... but I want two colors!

Comment: call drawstring for each different color

Comment: That's probably what I'm going to do, However that means having to do a manual layout if the entire string is supposed to be horizontally aligned. That's what I've been trying to avoid.

Comment: @Ian Warburton, I think the solution we're talking about is trhe best trade off if you just need to write soem text on a picture once for a special case.